# How to take my page higher in the search results?

Tags: google-search

To start with, I have a blog site and  its been 2 months now, since its been made live.
To make it SEO-Friendly, I have already followed the steps below:

1. All my page header is within h1 tag.
2. Added respective meta keywords, meta description and title tags.

But , when I copy paste a content from one of my meta keywords and paste it in the google, I dont find my page listed any where..

So, i am quite puzzled, as to what keyword should i use to take my page higher in the search results ?? also, are there any trust worthy SEO-tools which will help me identify the same ??

P.S : My website is hosted in a sub-domain e.g. blog.xyz.in

Comment: StackOverflow is for questions about programming. You might want to try this on [Pro Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use google's https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/ and google analytics, webmaster tools will help you optmize etc...